# Usage and meaning of Between and Among:

Tags: grammar

I happened to read a book and I saw the sentence :

I was sitting *between* my mother and father

But then I thought among would also fit the sentence:
I was sitting *among* my mother and father

I am actually unsure as both fit the sentence well and I also want to know their meaning and
usage in sentences.

Comment: Have you looked up both words in a dictionary?

Comment: There are more difficult examples at [between vs among](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you were sitting *between* them, you'd have the mother on one side and father on the other. It would be,

> Father, you, mother

or,

> Mother, you, father.

If you were sitting among them, then you could be sitting in any which way. You could be sitting in the pattern detailed above, or,

> You, mother/father, father/mother

and,

> Mother/father, father/mother, you

Hope this clears things up!

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense, despite having been accepted. @PrimeMover's answer is the correct one.

Comment: I wish to add that if the general seating plan is such that OP is *not* directly "between" mother and father, then the simple construct "sitting with my mother and father". The "among" word would simply not arise in this context.

Answer (score 1):

When I was at school, we were taught:

- "between" when there are 2 things to be mixed in with
- "among" when there are more than 2 things to be mixed in with.

This was specifically for when, say, you are dividing a bag of goodies: between 2 people, among 3 or more people.

However, that rule seems to work adequately here as well.

You would only use "between" if you are physically in between them, or nearly so: if you draw a straight line from your mother to your father, it would pass through (or close to) you on the way.

If you are *not* sitting "between" them as such, but are merely sitting so that the three of you form a close group, you would say "sitting *with* my mother and father".